# Graph algorithms on GPU

Tags: cuda, graph-theory, gpu

The current GPU execution and memory models are somehow limited (memory limit, limit of data structures, no recursion...).

Do you think it would be feasible to implement a graph theory problem on a GPU? For example, vertex cover? dominating set? independent set?  max clique?....

Is it also feasible to have branch-and-bound algorithms on GPUs? Recursive backtracking?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will be interested in

1. [**Exploring the Limits of GPUs With Parallel Graph Algorithms**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4482)
2. [**Accelerating large graph algorithms on the GPU using CUDA**](http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/papers/Pawan07accelerating.pdf).

Comment: Let's add this one, that has appeared in the mean time: [Accelerating CUDA Graph Algorithms at Maximum Warp](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.220.1923&rep=rep1&type=pdf). For certain graphs, it improves dramatically over the second result you link to.

Answer (score 5):

This is tangentially related to your question, but I've implemented a "recursive" backtracking algorithm for enumerating "self-avoiding walks" on a lattice (n.b.: the stack was simulated within the CUDA kernel, to avoid the overhead of creating local variables for a whole bunch of function calls). It's possible to do this efficiently, so I'm sure this can be adapted to a graph theoretical context. Here's a link to a seminar on the topic where I gave some general discussion about backtracking within the Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) paradigm; it's a pdf of about 1MB in size http://bit.ly/9ForGS .

I don't claim to know about the wider literature on graph theoretical algorithms on GPUs, but hope the above helps a little.

(@TheMachineCharmer, thanks for the links.)